# RAILS - How to fix I18n NoTranslationAvailable when using ISO3166::Country

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rubygems, rails-i18n, countries

I'm using https://rubygems.org/gems/countries in a project and trying to get all countries names using a locale string for translations.

The locale `'DE'`, `'NO'` or others are coming from the Google OCR API. The gem also has a method: `ISO3166::Country.translations`, which will return **all** the locale strings and the matching country, like: `"AL"=>"Albania"`.

In this list, there is also featured the translation `"NO"=>"Norway"`, but when using `ISO3166::Country.all_translated('NO')`, an error is thrown: `I18nData::NoTranslationAvailable: I18nData::NoTranslationAvailable -- countries-NO`.

Is there any workaround or fix to use all languages and get all translations? Or at least how is Norway not in the locales? The gem I think uses I18n as it's mentioned in the error, and the `:no` locale is not valid into I18n:

`I18n.locale = :no => I18n::InvalidLocale: :no is not a valid locale`

`I18n.locale = :de => :de`

Comment: The issue seems to be here https://github.com/grosser/i18n_data  - I see that the `countries-NO.txt` file is missing. Maybe open an issue there

Comment: @FlorinIonce, there are [`countries-NN.txt`](https://github.com/grosser/i18n_data/blob/master/cache/file_data_provider/countries-NN.txt) and [`countries-NB.txt`](https://github.com/grosser/i18n_data/blob/master/cache/file_data_provider/countries-NB.txt) in that list

Comment: @mechnicov Oh, you're right. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Norwegian i18n locales are [`:nn`](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/nn.yml) ([Nynorsk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nynorsk)) and [`:nb`](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/nb.yml) ([Bokmål](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bokm%C3%A5l)), not `:no`.

i18n uses [`countries-NN.txt`](https://github.com/grosser/i18n_data/blob/master/cache/file_data_provider/countries-NN.txt) and [`countries-NB.txt`](https://github.com/grosser/i18n_data/blob/master/cache/file_data_provider/countries-NB.txt)

So need to use `ISO3166::Country.all_translated('NN')` and `ISO3166::Country.all_translated('NB')`